# Schur-Weyl duality and denseness of unitaries

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Physicist here, so apologies for the imprecision.

The version of the Schur-Weyl duality I am interested in states that an operator $A$ that acts in the $k$-fold tensor product Hilbert space of $\mathcal{H}^{\otimes k}$ commutes with **all** operators $V^{\otimes k}$ where $V$ is a unitary on $\mathcal{H}$, iff $A$ is a linear combination of permutation operators that permutes the $k$ copies of $\mathcal{H}$. (Let's assume that the dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ is finite)

My question:
What precisely does "all" entail? Does the statement still hold if $V$ is not **any** unitary but is just dense in the set of all unitaries?

My guess: Probably yes, but how to be precise?

Motivation: in quantum computation a universal gate set allows us to get arbitrarily close (but technically not equal) to any unitary. I want to be careful this doesn't introduce pathological difficulties..

Comment: What does it mean to say an operator $V$ is dense? The set of unitary operators on $\cal H$ is closed (unless there's something different about infinite-dimensional spaces I don't understand), so any limit point of unitaries is unitary. Unless you mean $V$ is in the closure of the span of the $V^{\otimes n}$s for unitary operators $V$. I think an operator commutes with a set of operators iff it commutes with the closure of that set's span, so getting something from this should be workable.

Comment: I mean the set of $V$s obtainable from a universal gate set is only dense in the space of all unitaries.